# Get object attribute in class based view

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I wonder if it is possible to get the attribute of an object in Django Class Based Views.

What I try to do is the following:

I have an `UpdateView`:

```
class FooUpdate(UpdateView):
model = Foo

page_title = <foo-object's name should go here>
```

`page_title` is processed by the template with

```
...
<title>
    {{ view.page_title }}
</title>
...
```

(this technique is described [here](http://reinout.vanrees.org/weblog/2014/05/19/context.html))

`urls.py` looks like this:

```
...
url(r'^edit/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.FooUpdate.as_view(), name="edit")
...
```

How can I set `page_title` in the view?

I am aware that there are plenty other ways to achieve this, but setting a variable in the view was really convenient (up to now) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a mixin to achieve something similar.

```
class ContextMixin:
    extra_context = {}

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ContextMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update(self.extra_context)
        return context 

class FooUpdate(ContextMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Foo
    extra_context={'page_title': 'foo-objects name should go here'}
```

Edit: a different mixin, which feels bit hacky, but closer to what you want. I haven't tested it, but I think it should work.

```
class AutoContextMixin:

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AutoContextMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        for key in dir(self):
            value = getattr(self, key)
            if isinstance(value, str) and not key.startswith('_'):
                context[key] = value
        return context 

class FooUpdate(AutoContextMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Foo
    page_title = 'foo-objects name should go here'
```

Comment: thank you! but how would I need a mixin for that? The same could be done in `FooUpdate` itself, or not?

Comment: Yes, but with a mixin you can import and reuse the code in multiple classes and apps. So you don't have to write the `get_context_data` every time, when you only want to add some simple values.

Comment: I've added a second mixin example which might be closer to what you are after.

Answer (score 1):

No. You can't define attributes like that.

The nearest you could do would be to define a `page_title` method that returned `self.object.your_field`, but I don't see how that would be any better than overriding `get_context_data` and adding it there.

Comment: I would still have to adapt the template, right? In this case there is no advantage...